# i18n translation for "Back"-text in React Navigation on iOS

Tags: react-native, internationalization, react-navigation

I'm using [React Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/) and a StackNavigator in a React Native app. I'm able to translate the `navigationOptions.title`, however, on iOS if there is too much text in the header it defaults to showing the text "Back" next to the back button. I don't mind this, but I want it to say "Back" in my current language. How can I achieve this? The text I'm talking about:

[image: Back button]

An example of how I use the `navigationOptions` now:

```
class Example extends Component<Props> {
    static navigationOptions = () => ({
        title: i18n.t('example_title'),
    });
    // ...
}
```

In case it is relevant we're using [`react-native-localize`](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-localize) with [`i18n-js`](https://github.com/fnando/i18n-js) for the i18n functionality. I don't want it to always say the previous screens name, or always back, I want it dynamically as it is now, just with i18n.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `navigationOptions` object has an key for this called [`headerTruncatedBackTitle`](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-navigator.html#headertruncatedbacktitle).

> Title string used by the back button when `headerBackTitle` doesn't fit on the screen. "Back" by default. `headerTruncatedBackTitle` has to be defined in the origin screen, not in the destination screen.

You can for example utilize this with i18n simply by doing:

```
class Example extends Component<Props> {
    static navigationOptions = () => ({
        title: i18n.t('example_title'),
        headerTruncatedBackTitle: i18n.t('example_back'), // "Back", "Zurück", etc.
    });
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In my application in Main AppStack createStackNavigator where you combine all of your screens, I have added a second parameter an object in which we give it a key

```
    createStackNavigator({
       ...screens
    },

    {
       defaultNavigationOptions: { 
          headerBackTitle: i18n.t('example_title')
       }
    })
```

This will set the Back button to the current language of the entire application.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. While `headerBackTitle` is good, I don't see a way to make it work dynamically. That is, show either the previous `title` OR the text "Back". I would ideally like it to stay like it is (dynamic), but add i18n to the "Back" text.

Comment: I do, just use a function instead of object, in the function you receive screen props which you can set on your navigation container.The test is explained in the docs if you are interested let me know to post an answer.